# How to find if all the list of strings exits in another list in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I was trying out to find a way to find if all the elements of a list exists in another list. Tried the below code but still didn't work out.

```
#!/usr/intel/bin/python2.7

# Global Import Variables
import Tkinter, Tkconstants, tkFileDialog
import warnings
import os.path

search_line = []
search_line.append('APPLE')
search_line.append('MANGO_REQUEST')
search_line.append('SeaPort')

line = []
linez = "helo how are APPLE helloo.log.gz you MANGO_REQUEST life is cool and as usual SeaPort"
linez = linez.split()
print linez

print search_line
print linez

if all(x in search_line for x in linez):
    print "final result"
    print linez
```

But it never satisfied the equation. Is there anything getting missed ? Please share in your thoughts.

Thanks !

Comment: Don't you want to check if everything *in `search_line`* is in `linez`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your condition:

```
if all(x in search_line for x in linez):
```

you're checking if all 'words' from `linez` exist in your `search_line` list which is obviously `False`, you want to do it the other way around:

```
if all(x in linez for x in search_line):
```